# WAMP installation and IPV6

Tags: server, wamp, ipv6

I'm having a rather annoying problem with my home setup where I  have two computers, a table PC and a laptop, connected in a home network. I have installed a WAMP server on my laptop to act as a server and the laptop is now running `Windows 10`. I noticed a significant drop in speed lately and pinpointed the problem being `IPV6` in the laptop resulting in `localhost/phpmyadmin` being very slow taking one table 30 seconds to load slowing down my work.

When I still had `Windows 8` I disabled the `IPV6` connection by inserting a registery `DWORD DisabledComponents` into Windows Registry, but now that I have `Windows 10` and after attempting to reconnect to home group the system prompted me to re-activate `IPV6`.

Now is there any way to speed up WAMP with `IPV6`? This is beginning to be a problem as `IPV6` is starting to be used by some web addresses (like Google) of course having `IPV4` too but still.

Answer (score 0):

Your percieved speed issues could be due to so many things from just not enough muscle in the laptop to run a webserver + Database Server + PHP + etc etc, its impossible to guess a good answer.

However it might be worth doing some optimisation before throwing the IPV6 baby out with the bath water!

- First, in W10 Microsoft seemed to think it was a good idea to install IIS by default. If you are not using it, you can quite happily remove it.
- It often makes connections to MySQL run quicker if you use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` as the host, although this is now the default in the WAMPServer's phpMyAdmin configuration, its worth checking to see you have not chnaged it back to `localhost` for some reason.
- In later versions of MySQL they changed a default value that can make the `table_definition_cache` hog large amounts of memory, as much as half a gig.

I have found I can reduce the memory footprint of a resting MySQL server by adding this parameter to the `my.ini` with a more sensible default like so without causing any obvious detremental effects to MYSQL's performance.

```
table_definition_cache = 600
```

Using this can free up 3 to 4 hundered meg of memory that was probably not being used, especially as the default database engine is now INNODB anyway.

- If you are reloading large database backups etc, its probably quicker to use the `mysql.exe` command line processor than phpMyAdmin.

  left click wampmnager -> MySQL -> MySQL console

Then use the `source` command from the mysql command prompt i.e.

```
mysql > source '/path/to/file.sql';
```